# Projection from pseudometric space into metric identification preserves topologies

Tags: metric-spaces

I've just started working through a topology textbook, and I'm sure I'm being silly, but I can't for the life of me make any headway on the following question:

Let $(M,\rho)$ be a pseudometric space, $(M^*,\rho^*)$ its metric identification, $h(x)$ the canonical projection map from $M\to M^*$.

Then a set $A$ in $M$ is closed (open) iff $h(A)$ is closed (open) in $M^*$.

I have $A$ in $M$ open $\implies$ $h(A)$ open in $M^*$.

The thing that's tripping me up is considering say:

$\{1,2\}$ with the trivial pseudometric. The metric identification is $\{[1]\}$, so $\{[1]\}$ is open in the metric identification, but $\{1\}$ is not open in the pseudometric space, since every disk around $1$ contains $2$ as well.

Thanks I'm sure I'm probably doing something stupid, but after googling it I couldn't find an explanation so I came here.

Comment: This mistake is in the exercise 2C.3 on page 20 of the book *General Topology* (1970) by Stephen Willard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The characterization of the topology on $M$ that you have written (which, I see, is the characterization on the [wikipedia page for pseudometrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudometric_space)) has an error.

It should be: "a set $A$ in $M$ is closed (open) iff **$A$ is saturated and** $h(A)$ is closed (open) in $M^*$".

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but what is the definition of saturated?

Yeah I checked wiki after I read this in my textbook and was kind of surprised to see it there too.

Comment: A subset $A \subset M$ is *saturated* if for every $x,y \in M$, if $x \in A$ and if $x,y$ have the same image in $M^*$ then $y \in A$. Another way to say it is that a saturated subset of $M$ is the same thing as the preimage of a subset of $M^*$ under the canonical projection.

Comment: Awesome that's sorta what I expected it to be thanks.